# Monotone convergence when $f_n$ is decreasing

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I know that if $f_n\geq 0$, that $(f_n)$ is increasing and that if $\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n=f\in L^1$, then,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int f_n=\int f.$$

Does this result also work when $(f_n)$ is decreasing ?

Comment: No, because that would not give the other side of the inequality given by Fatou's lemma.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: But using dominated convergence, don't we have that $|f_n|\leq f_1\in L^1$ for all $n$ (because $f_n$ decreasing) and thus, using dominated convergence theorem, $\lim_{n\to \infty }\int f_n=\int f$ ?

Comment: @MathBeginner You are right. If $f_1 \in L^1$, it is true. You can even take the sequence $f_1-f_n$ and use monotone convergence instead of dominated convergence.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Yes, it is true. My mistake earlier, I offer apologies.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Great, thank you :-)

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: Thank you :-)

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

If $f_1 \in L^1$ (or any element of the sequence belongs to $L^1$), the dominated convergence theorem (or the monotone convergence theorem applied to $g_n=f_1-f_n$) give you your result.

If not, then it isn't true. For instance, take $f_n=\infty \cdot \chi_ {[0,1/n]}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_{n}=\frac{1}{n}χ[0,n]$.

For every $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $N > 1$
 such that
$|f_n(x)| < \epsilon $ for every $n>N$. Hence, $f_n$ converges to $f = 0$ ,uniformly. However, 
$$0 = \int
f d\lambda \not= \lim \int
f_n d\lambda = 1$$
The MCT does not apply because the sequence is not monotone increasing. Fatou’s
lemma obviously applies.

Comment: $f_n$ is not decreasing.